# this.Type reserved ? Should be reported

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I discovered yesterday that I can't have a Class that uses a field named "Type" this is probably reserved.

Although the field may be reserved you still can't set anyObject.Type if it doesn't have a Type field defined as a public string. Ignoring any getters and setters and jumping directly to changing YourObject to "whatever" string.

Try this for yourself. Define a Type field and try setting it.

This should be reported to Microsoft so no one will use "Type" as a field in the future, there is no warnings/errors along trying to define it.

```
        public Point_Extended(Point p, booking b)
        {
            this.ID = p.ID;
            this.Type = p.Type;
            this.Status = p.Status;
            this.Size = p.Size;
            this.Coords = p.Coords;
            this.Color = p.Color;
            this.BuildingID = p.BuildingID;

            this.Login = b.Login;
            this.Starts = b.Starts;
            this.Hours = b.Hours;
            this.BookingID = b.ID;
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you provide your code sample yourself so we can verify it, also which version of C# are you using? I doubt there's merit to your story but I can't do anything about it unless your post all your findings, including source code.

Comment: Are you also going to try to define a `String` class?

Comment: "This should be reported to Microsoft so no one will use "Type" as a field in the future, there is no warnings/errors along trying to define it." <facepalm />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.

It was the ToString() override representation that confused me to think the Type was changed.

Answer (score 4):

If there is a name abiguity - just use `this.Type` / `obj.Type` (instance), `TypeName.Type` (static) or `System.Type` (the type). Or in really nasty cases, `global::System.Type`. This works just fine and matches the question (I think):

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main() {
        Test anyObject = new Test();
        anyObject.Type = "abc";
    }
}
class Test
{
    public string Type;
}
```

Comment: Hello Marc thanks for your reply.

I updated the first post with my constructor in my class.

I already use this.Type and p.Type is a string "rect" ..

Using your example doesn't change the actual type of the Test class to "abc", so why wouldn't it work on my class ?

Thanks alot!

Comment: @dezza - unless you show the entire class, I have no way of reproducing this. For example, what is `Point`? does *that* have a `.Type`? Can you post a **reproducible** example please?

Comment: I'm sorry .. I thought you only needed info about the .Type setting .. No need to be holding hidden cards ..

http://pastebin.com/Z07pv9rV

Comment: @dezza - OK, I grabbed that from pastebin, fixed up all the typos (`Point` vs `point` etc) errors, invented `Exceptions` and `dbDataContext`, and it compiled. Cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining "Type" in a scope local to your class, e.g.

```
class SomeClass
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

and then using it in some method of that class, e.g.

```
class SomeClass
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        Type = "Foo";
    }
}
```

This is ambiguous between "Type" in SomeClass (a property) and "Type" in namespace System (a type).

Comment: Should it also be ambiguous when using this.Type ? Using Marc's sample it works fine, but when using my own it still changes the type.